# laravel 5: PDOException: connectino actively refused

Tags: php, database, laravel, exception

we are trying to work with laravel, we have to make a connection with our database on a ubuntu virtual machine.
our env file is filled in correctly, but when we get the exception, it says that it tries to make connection to localhost instead the ip of the virtual machine (but the user, port etc is correct and different from default values)

we tried to restart the webserver, changed the default values in database.php, but no luck

Comment: try clearing config cache `php artisan config:clear`, make sure Laravel loads the correct values buly debugging or work with `php artisan tinker` and dump environmental variables to see what is happening.

Comment: Show me the error message